# What is the difference between laptop screen and desktop screen?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I have HP laptop with 17 inch screen and I bought a new screen 22 inch and connect it to my laptop. I noticed that the quality of text and content of the laptop screen feels better. Is there any thing that I can do for the new screen to make its quality similar to the laptop screen?

Comment: Connected with a VGA cable? Is the secondary monitor set to use it's native resolution? Right click on your desktop and select `Resolution` or `Properties` to view the monitor details.

Comment: Yes with VGA cable. I did right click.... But how can I know if it uses a native resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Are you extending your desktop or duplicating it on both monitors?

If you are duplicating, the resolution will be the highest resolution supported by both displays, which means one display might not be operating at the native resolution (usually the larger one, because the smaller display the smaller the native resolution).

If you are extending your desktop, you should see two monitors when you open Screen Resolution settings (as canadmos suggested, provided you are using Windows). You can click on either and make sure they have their native resolution. Newer versions of Windows show "(Recommended)" after the native resolution.

If your 22" monitor is at its native resolution, then you might have a bad cable.

Comment: Second the bad cable part.  VGA cables can be slightly bad creating a bad image on the destination monitor.  Not bad enough that they don't work altogether, just bad enough that the image is bad.  Try another cable.